# How to subprocess call with environment variable?

Tags: python, linux, macos, subprocess, debian

I can use use `subprocess` to list files like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('ls')
```

But if I change command to display contents of `$PATH` environment variable:

```
subprocess.call('echo $PATH')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/pyhton/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['echo $PATH'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/user/Downloads/pyhton/main.py"]
[dir: /Users/user/Downloads/pyhton]
[path: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin]
```

Also tried:

```
subprocess.call(['echo', '$PATH'])
```

Which just print `$PATH`, not its contents.

1) What is the proper way of doing it?

2) Can I add some path to `$PATH` and then call an application on that path by doing:

```
subprocess.call(['PATH=$PATH:/usr/app_path', 'app'])
```

or there is an even smarter way of doing such a thing? I mean calling an app which is not on PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Python2.7, you can run the subprocess command as follows:

```
res = subprocess.check_output('echo $PATH', shell=True)
print(res)
```

Regarding updating your `$PATH` env variable, try:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "path/to/add"
```

Comment: Got `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'`

Comment: Yes I have `import subprocess`. Here with Python 2.7 on macOS I keep getting that error.

Comment: @KcFnMi oh, python2.7. Didn't know that people still work with it :). I will update my solution in a few..

Comment: Well, looks like 2.7 is the default on macOS and (if I'm not wrong) Debian 10. If they keep it way should I change )

Comment: @KcFnMi try now please :)

Comment: The Pyhton 2.7 approach works fine here. Would you make any comment about item 2 of question? I guess there is a better way of achieving that but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Oh, I missed it. I've updated my solution, please check it out...